# Disable project build for a particular configuration in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have one Solution with three Projects.

- Project X
- Project 1
- Project 2

Project 1 builds Project X as a dependency *with* a particular pre-processor definition `TESTING` and then performs link to create an exe.  This is achieved using build configuration Y.

Project 2 builds Project X as a dependency *without* said pre-processor definition and then performs link to create an exe.  This is achieved using one of the two default build configurations, namely Debug or Release.

If the build configuration for the Solution is set to Y, Project 2 doesn't build when the Solution is built, but that doesn't stop anyone from right-clicking Project 2 in configuration Y and selecting build.  Project 2 will fail to build in this case since it relies on Project X being built without said pre-processor definition, that is, not configuration Y.

Is there a way to hide/disable Project 2 if the Solution configuration is set as Y or is this only possible with a separate Solution file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing Project 2 in its property pages to instead be defined as a [Utilility project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa733962(v=vs.60)).  This has the effect of compiling object files for Project 2 but not performing the link stage under Solution configuration Y.